# Passing value from combo ox to textbox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Hello i have a combox box with values from sql and i want the selected value to be printed in a textbox. This is the sql code of the combo box

```
Public Sub fillClientcombo()

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select id, name from clients", con)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        Dim table As New DataTable
        da.Fill(table)
        Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow
        row(0) = 0
        row(1) = "Select Clients"
        table.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)
        ComboBox1.DataSource = table
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "name"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "id"

    End Sub
```

And this is the combo box private sub where i make the textbox to get the selected value

```
  Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
      
        TextBox2.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        

    End Sub
```

But when i run  it i get this line printed

**System.Data.DataRowView**

Comment: Try once TextBox2.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C# so don't tag it C#. Tags are not a way for you to get more eyes on your question dishonestly. They are for us, to tell us whether a question is relevant to us. Only apply a tag if it specifically relates to your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the same `name` value that you see in the `ComboBox` then use this:

```vb
TextBox2.Text = ComboBox1.Text
```

If you actually want the corresponding `id` value then use this:

```vb
TextBox2.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

Of course, you don't need any code at all if you bind the `TextBox` when you bind the `ComboBox`:

```vb
TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", table, "name")
```

You can specify `"id"` instead of `"name"` if that's what you want.